# How to Resolve Hyper-V Disk Location to Drive Letter

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, storage-area-network, diskmanagement, cluster-shared-volumes

When viewing cluster disk properties in Failover Manager or the physical path to VHD's in the settings of a VM in Hyper-V Manager the location is displayed by GUID.  Is there a quick way find out which GUID is mapped to which drive letter with powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view the current mapped drives and their respective device id's run the following script:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_volume | select name,deviceid | ft -AutoSize
```

The output displays two columns, the first the drive letter, and the second is the device ID displaying the GUID.

To find the drive letter for a specific GUID try this:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_volume | Where-Object {$_.DeviceID -like "*GUID*"} | select name
```